# How to install IPA file in iphone4s

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipa

I created a ipa file without provisional to test the app. how to install this ipa file directly from iphone. I downloaded that IPA file using itunes gmail account app. after downloaded the IPA file I cannot find that IPA file which is downloaded. how to find that file and install that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to run an app on a non jailbroken device, you need to create the ipa file using a provisioning file that includes your device. Otherwise, it would be impossible to install that file on the device (unlike on Android, where you can send the apk from one device to another and install it freely via email). If you do have an account as part of the iOS Developer Program, you will need to go to the Developer Portal, create a development certificate, create an app ID, register your device, create a provisioning profile that matches all of the previous details and use that profile when running your app on the physical device.